# Jenkins doc job error: rosdep thriftpy

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, jenkins, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this error in the Jenkins doc job of my package: http://build.ros.org/view/Mdoc/job/Mdoc__z_laser_projector__ubuntu_bionic_amd64/2/console

```
04:09:39 /tmp/ws/src/z_laser_projector/doc/zlp_core.rst:4: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'zlp_core'; the following exception was raised:
04:09:39 Traceback (most recent call last):
04:09:39   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 658, in import_object
04:09:39     __import__(self.modname)
04:09:39   File "/tmp/ws/src/z_laser_projector/src/z_laser_projector/zlp_core.py", line 29, in <module>
04:09:39     import thriftpy
04:09:39 ImportError: No module named thriftpy
```

I'm trying to solve it including dependencies in my package.xml:

```
  <build_depend>python3-thriftpy</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>python3-thriftpy</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>python3-thriftpy</exec_depend>
```

However, when I try to build the package at Travis-CI (in private before try in Jenkins), it throws this error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
z_laser_projector: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [python3-thriftpy]
The command "rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

How could I include this dependency in order to fix the Jenkins job? Am I taking the right way to solve the error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366255/jenkins-doc-job-error:-rosdep-thriftpy/) by [rluque](https://answers.ros.org/users/55521/rluque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2020-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Package.xml dependencies are resolved with rosdep. In order to be resolvable with the default sources, rosdep definitions need to be added. You can read about contributing those here: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#rosdep-rules-contributions

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2020-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-25**:
Just to add to this: `package.xml` does not use the name of a Python package or the name of a Debian version of that Python package *directly*.

All names in package manifests are actually *keys*, which get looked up in a database (called the `rosdep` DB). The result of that mapping is then used to check for presence of and to install a package.

So if `python3-thriftpy` is not already registered in the `rosdep` DB, you can add the name to your manifest, but that won't help. `rosdep` will still not be able to "understand" it. That's what

> Cannot locate rosdep definition for [python3-thriftpy]

means.

This may seem rather convoluted, but there are good reasons for this system. See #q215059 for a Q&A which discusses this.

**Comment by [rluque](https://answers.ros.org/users/55521/rluque/) on 2020-12-22**:
Thank you very much for your help! I asked for adding python3-thriftpy depend at rosdep. See here: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/27582